# Naming conventions pattern: Collection and Collections?

Tags: java, design-patterns

not asking the functionality of Collection or the Collections classes in Java. i see this pattern everywhere where you have a class called e.g. "Animal" and another class called "Animals". is there a design pattern into play here or is it just general convention?

Answer (score 2):

1.`Collection` is not class.

2.design pattern is for solving a certain type of problem. your question has nothing to do with design pattern. it could be a naming convention thing. e.g. `guava` has `Lists, Maps...`, however you could name your class as `Animal and AnimalUtil, AnimalHelper, AnimalTools whatever` You name it as `AnimalFactory` doesn't mean it applied `Factory pattern`. Just name.

Comment: but everyone seems to be following the same convention. java is filled with many examples. it has to be something....!

Comment: looks like this is static factory method pattern from joshua bloch

Answer (score 1):

No specific design pattern here. Collections contains utility methods applicable for collection related classes. Another example is [Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class from jdk 7 that contains utility operations you can perform on any object instance.